# Proof for Homologous cycles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Prove that two cycles that surround the same holes differ by a boundary i.e. the relation for calling two cycles homologous as mentioned here.

http://jeremykun.com/2013/04/03/homology-theory-a-primer/

Comment: What does it mean to "surround the same holes," especially in dimension $\geq 2$? For that matter, the torus $T^2$ presumably has one "hole," but $H_1(T^2) = \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @anomaly there are two holes: one longitudinal and one latitudinal.

Comment: @JeremyKun: There are obviously two generators of $H_1(T^2)$ (or $\pi_1(T^2))$, but I don't see more than one hole in the torus; it has genus $1$.

Comment: The generators describe the holes. The torus is hollow, so the "inside" is a hole. It's not what you mean when you say a "one-holed torus," but that's just an overloading of the informal term "hole."

Comment: That is the point of algebraic topology: we can now use algebra to *define* holes instead of fuzzy geometric ideas.

Answer (score 1):

What it means to "surround the same hole" is that the two cycles are in the same homology class (it also depends on the multiplicity, not just which holes are surrounded), and so by definition their difference is a boundary.

I think what you're looking to do is prove that homology is well-defined. This is not a trivial task, but the standard reference is Chapter 2 of [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf).

The idea, however, is the same as the idea of fundamental groups. You can go around one cycle in one direction, then the other in the reverse direction. This is a "closed loop" whose interior doesn't include the hole, and is hence a boundary.

Comment: By definition their difference is a boundary. Can you please show me how ?

Comment: One defines the informal statement, "surrounding the same hole (with multiplicity)" as "being in the same homology class." And two cycles are in the same homology class (by definition) if their difference is a boundary. It's not trivial to see that this relation is an equivalence relation, but that's what I mean when I call it "well-defined."

Comment: Ok. Pls explain how the homology quotient group achieves this thing that two holes whose difference is a boundary belong to the same coset.

Comment: And i understand the definition of holes and boundaries. What i dont get is how difference of holes(cycles bounding geometric holes in topological space) can generate a boundary. Since hole cycles themselves form a subgroup of the cycles' group

Comment: Boundaries are also cycles, but they are cycles that don't surround any holes. It's hard to visualize because they're not proper paths like the fundamental group (they're formal linear combinations of cycles), but it's the same intuition: when you take a difference of holes the "interior" can change, because the interior of a cycle depends on the orientation and subtracting reverses orientation.